# Are we able to use App Maker to publish a revenue generating app in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-app-maker

For example, I would like to be able to create an app, that allow people to log in, and report a possible catastrophic fire by clicking on a button, that then forwards an e-mail to us.

We want the app that we create with App Maker to be able to have in app purchases, be able to accept advertising, and be published in Google Play.

Does App Maker allow you to create revenue generating apps for Google Play or just apps for your business?

Answer (score 0):

- Apps created with App Maker cannot be published to Google Play
- Apps created  App Maker don't have any built-in monetization or advertisement mechanisms
- Developers can create and publish application only within one domain/organization (in other words web sites created with App Maker are not public-facing)

Comment: Do you know of any Google tools(or any other reputable company such as Microsoft) where we can use simple drag and drop interfaces such as App Maker to build an app for Google Android? I have no coding experience. Please exclude all those companies that allow you to use their programming to build an app, but retain ownership of the app that you create with their tools.